# Load JSON from stdin before starting Python REPL

Tags: python, bash

By loading JSON from stdin before starting the REPL, I can pipe JSON outputs from other commands and work with the JSON data in Python.

I've tried something like and it worked:

`kubectl get po -o json | cp /dev/stdin /tmp/data.json && python -i -c "import json; data = json.load(open('/tmp/data.json'))" && rm /tmp/data.json`

Now I want to make it a script, so I write the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
tmp_file=$(mktemp /tmp/ipyjson.XXXXXX)
cp /dev/stdin $tmp_file
python -i -c "import json; data = json.load(open('$tmp_file')); print(data)"
rm $tmp_file
```

And change the previous command to `kubectl get po -o json | new_script`.

But this time the REPL quits immediately after starting up, I have no idea what's the difference here. Maybe something about the interactive mode?

**Edit**:

I've also tried reading `sys.stdin` directly and met the same issue:

```
❯ k get po -o json | ipython -i -c "import sys, json; data = json.load(sys.stdin)"
Python 3.10.2 (main, Feb 11 2022, 14:13:20) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.4.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)?
```

As you can see, `ipython` quited immediately with the prompt "Do you really want to exit ([y]/n)?".

Comment: You can just read the JSON from stdin with `json.load(sys.stdin)`. No need to a temporary file, just something like `kubectl get po -o json | python yourfile.py`.

Comment: I've tried that. `python` or `ipython` would quit immediately, it's like the stdin is consumed and so the REPL decides to quit.

Comment: BTW, I'm using macOS.

Comment: Show us the call and code of that try!

Comment: @KlausD. I've edited my question with detail about the `sys.stdin` attempt.

Comment: You have to create a python file. `-c` code does not work for that.

Comment: If you mean something like `xxx | ipython -i yourfile.py` and then load JSON in `yourfile.py`, that doesn't work for me. 
The REPL just quit.

Comment: I think the problem is that `python` or `ipython` depends on `stdin` to read lines of codes, so we should not mess with it. That's why I tried writing to a temp file first.
But I'm not sure how to make `python` or `ipython` use a separate STDIN when I run them in a script.

Comment: Have you tried `#!/bin/bash` instead fo `#!/bin/bash -i`

Comment: To make it top clear: The REPL can not read any data from stdin because it reads the code from there. So, no `-i` and no `-c`. Just `python yourfile.py` as I wrote above.

Comment: The whole point is to start the REPL here.